# II7 rewrite rule for (htm|html|asp) to php if file doesn't exist

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have an old website done using classic ASP and also HTM/HTML files.

Now I want to rename the files to .php but keep the url as .asp, or .html

www.example.com/some/page.htm to www.example.com/some/page.php
www.example.com/another_page.asp to www.example.com/another_page.php
and so on..

I have tried this one inspired by another answer found here:

```
<rule name="HTML to PHP">
    <match url="^(.*)\.htm$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}.php" />
</rule>
```

But I don't know if it works because I have to contact my hosting to apply the changes I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action tag to:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php" />
```

And you might want to consider adding the query string as well (if provided) with:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php" appendQueryString="true" />
```